# How to organize and use Web Components?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to use web components, but I don't want to write all the contents in the same file. How to implement it? person-panel in index.html has been added in the server,not js.

file structure

- /index.html
- /index.js
- /PersonPanel/personPanel.js
- /PersonPanel/template.html

index.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="index.js" type="module" />
  </head>
<body>
<person-panel></person-panel>
</body>
</html>
```

index.js

```
import personPanel from './PersonPanel/personPanel.js';
// other operations that may require a PersonPanel
```

template.html

```
<template>
<label class="field"></label>
</template>
```

personPanel.js

```
class PersonPanel extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
     super();
     this.attachShadow({mode : 'open'});
     // how to fetch template?
  }
  static get observedAttributes() {
    return ['field'];
  }

  attributeChangedCallback(name, oldValue, newValue) {
     if(name == 'field'){
       this.shadowRoot.querySelector('label.field').innerText = newValue;
     }
  }
}
window.customElements.define('person-panel', PersonPanel);
export default PersonPanel;
```

Comment: You're already using ECMAScript modules, so what's the problem? Just `import` them all into `index.js` and add some setup function to call.

Comment: If it's not much trouble, try React because it is very helpful when you want to divide your code into many components.